# Home Router - How to make USB HD available online to map in Windows?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, external-hard-drive

I have a router with openWRT and a connected USB HD. Is it possible to setup it so the HD is available online and that I can map in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The generic answer is 'yes, it is possible'. For example, if you have enough space on the router, you could install Samba package (http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/cifs.server) to share your hard drive in the Windows network. There should be also other protocols to connect the drive, like iSCSI (https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/8798), but there is a very small chance, that you need it.

Comment: Is it possible that when I'm in that LAN all the file access happens inside the LAN and when I'm home the access happens by WAN/internet? Can it automatically switch it? perhaps by making 2 ways to connect it, one by local IP and the other by internet IP? Can that happens simultaneously or I must choose one only? I don't like the idea that even when all the pc's are in the same LAN I still use Internet to access it. Lost of bandwidth.

Comment: Is it possible that when I'm in that LAN all the file access happens inside the LAN and when I'm home the access happens by WAN/internet? Can it automatically switch it? perhaps by making 2 ways to connect it, one by local IP and the other by internet IP? Can that happens simultaneously or I must choose one only? I don't like the idea that even when all the pc's are in the same LAN I still use Internet to access it. Lost of bandwidth.